# PHP: result of functions turned back to a string

Tags: php, function, eval

I have a template .php file with a bunch of functions in it to render out html. Here is a snippet:

```
$j ='    
table("tb_02", "600", "", "ebebeb", "right", "top", "30 0 30 0","Table content...");
//whole bunch of similar functions here...
';
```

The table function looks like this:

```
    function table($tbID, $tbWidth, $tbHeight, $tbBgColor, $tbHzAlign, $tbVtAlign, $tbPad, $tbContent) {
// code omitted here     
$a = "
          <table id=\"$tbID\" width=\"$tbWidth\" $tbHeight $tbBgColor border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
              <td valign=\"$tbVtAlign\" align=\"$tbHzAlign\" width=\"$tbWidth\" style=\"$pad\">
        $tbContent
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
        "; 
          echo $a;
        };
```

What I want to do is turn the result of $j in the template .php file (which will be html only - no php) into a string. The issue I'm having is that I first need it eval'd (the  result of the functions, and then convert that). I'm after something like this, but can't find a way to get the eval'd code back to a string:

```
$j = eval($j);
$j = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $j);
$j = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $j);
echo $j;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `eval()` can and WILL cause you major amounts of grief in the future. and if you insist on writing code like this, at least learn how to use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s so you can eliminate 'leaning toothpick syndrome'.

Comment: The whole thing (`eval()`, concatenating HTML with unescaped strings, generating HTML using string concatenation, using `echo` inside the `table()` function, etc, etc) is very, very bad practice. You should seriously consider refactoring.

Comment: Instead of saving the function call in a string, use an array.  Store the parameters in it, then use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call the function.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to echo the table, why not have `table()` `return` instead of `echo`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, `eval()` calls many functions, not just `table()`, apparently.

Comment: @rid: So?  You can call functions dynamically with `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, sure, I was referring to the problem of returning from these functions (that was my initial answer)... He'd need to change the evaluated code to make this work.

Comment: Why not look for a *real* PHP templating system?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, no arguing with that (see my previous comment)... PHP itself can be very successfully used as a templating system as well, there's really nothing extra to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've switched the table function to return. It was set as echo because the template file itself also needs to be echo'd (inside a preview window). In the end I'm after a solution to display the template file (rendered in preview window), but also the result as a string so I can screen preview the code and then fwrite it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is *not* a templating system.  It's slow, unsafe, and shouldn't be used.  There is always a better way to do things.

I suggest looking around for a *real* templating system, what you are doing is very bad practice.

First off, your functions should be `return`ing data, not `echo`ing it.  That way, you can manipulate it, and `echo` it out all at once.

Second, have a look at [`HEREDOC`s](http://php.net/heredoc), they'll make your life easier.

```
function table($tbID, $tbWidth, $tbHeight, $tbBgColor, $tbHzAlign, $tbVtAlign, $tbPad, $tbContent) {
    // code omitted here     
    $a = <<<HTML
    <table id="$tbID" width="$tbWidth" $tbHeight $tbBgColor border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="$tbVtAlign" align="$tbHzAlign" width="$tbWidth" style="$pad">$tbContent</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
HTML;

    return $a;
}
```

Lastly, you shouldn't be trying to `eval` strings, it's pad practice.  My suggestion may not be any better practice, but it's better than `eval`.

Instead of `$j` being a string, try making it an array.

```
$j = array(
    'table' => array("tb_02", "600", "", "ebebeb", "right", "top", "30 0 30 0","Table content...")
);
```

Now what you can do, is use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to "eval" the code.

```
$html = '';

foreach($j as $func=>$args){
    $x = call_user_func_array($func, $args);

    $x = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $x);
    $x = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $x);

    $html .= $x;
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: `table("tb_02", "600", "", "ebebeb", "right", "top", "30 0 30 0",  
      font("f_01", "century", "12px", "000000", "bold", $header01)
      .font("f_02", "century", "12px", "000000", "", $content01)
      .hyperLink("l_01", "century", "18px", "770000", "bold", "none", "http://", "Click Here")      
      .font("f_03", "century", "12px", "000000", "", $content02)
      );` Here is my full code. It is for html emails, which is why everything is inlined and redundant. How would I put this into the array?

Comment: @John: You're gonna need to refactor it.  Don't have it all as one line.  You can "eval" the `font().font().hyperlink().font()` part first, then use that result for `table()`.